# How to read the content of a CSV file without uploading it in Angular 6

Tags: csv, angular6, file-read

I am having a problem when reading the data of a CSV file on my local development server with Angular 6. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
http.get('some_folder/local_csv_file.csv')
```

Comment: I want to get data from your command but I don't know how to do it. I have seen this article http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/10/read-csv-data-using-angular-2.html#.W7xj-WgzaUl but it work wrongly.

Comment: First learn what a Promise is in Javascript and learn how to use it. 
Then open that article (the one you used) again and you will probably able to make it work.